# LINQ to SQL: Selecting a one-to-many relationship

Tags: linq, nested, one-to-many

I've got two tables (articles and tags) that have a one-to-many relationship.

I remember seeing somewhere that I can create nested objects/arrays/etc from that relationship. The output of which I would like in a format such as (in JSON format):

```
{1 : {
    id : 1,
    title : 'article title',
    tags : ({
        id : 16,
        tagname : 'first tag'
    },{
        id : 23,
        tagname : 'another tag'
    })
}
```

I'm creating an internal knowledge base system with a list view similar to the front page of stack overflow (that's the way I'd like to display the tags).

How would I go about doing this? A subquery? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you're looking for the `SelectMany` function which lets you 'unroll' nested structures like yours.  `SelectMany` **is** indeed executed in Query syntax by a sub-query:

```
IEnumerable<Tag> = 
    from article in Articles
    from tag in article.Tags
    select tag;
```

In method form:

```
IEnumerable<Tag> tags = Articles.SelectMany(a => a.Tags);
```

Comment: So for this to work, I need to setup my .dbml file correctly?

Comment: Yessir.  The GUI should work just fine, however.  (What version of VS are you using?)

Comment: Unsavory alternative to using the .dbml file: loading things manually with ADO.NET (and hand-written SQL) and using Linq to Objects.

Comment: If your dbml file is set up correctly you should be able to do this perfectly.  You'd want to define it in terms of smallest to largest units: define how to transform a Tag object to the JSON string you want, then define how to transform an Article object to the JSON string you want in terms of the Tag object's transformation method.

Comment: Okay, I finally got the above code to return the tags working, but how do I get the entire article + tags resultset?

Comment: You could group the results by article.